# Wildcard array loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains a great deal of data, which has been generated from a JSON file. Most of the data is used to populate`input` elements, but some of the keys contain hidden, default values to be used for calculations later.

The array looks something like this:

```
[name] => 'My App'
[default_E17] => 0.009
[default_H17] => 0.0236
[default_K17] => 50
[default_P17] => 0.0118
[default_E19] => 0.03
```

I want to loop over all `default_*` keys, and output them using HTML. Essentially, I want a `foreach` loop, but only for the keys whose format matches `default_*`. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Please note that the values in the array before `[default_*]` keys is variable length, so I cannot easily use an `array_splice()`.

Comment: you have to iterate over the whole array and check the key for a matching pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `strpos($key, "default_") === 0` to show that it start with `default_` and its not in the middle or end

```
$array = array();
$array['name'] = 'My App';
$array['default_E17'] = "0.009";
$array['default_H17'] = "0.0236";
$array['default_K17'] = "50";
$array['default_P17'] = "0.0118";
$array['default_E19'] = "0.03";
$array['E19_default_test'] = "1.03";


echo "<pre>";
```

*** You can use `foreach` ***

```
$list = array();
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if (strpos($key, "default_") === 0) {
        $list[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($list);
```

***You can also use `array_flip` with `array_filter`***

```
$array = array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($array),function($var) { return (strpos($var, "default_") === 0);}));
var_dump($array);
```

***You can also use `FilterIterator`***

```
class RemoveDefaultIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return (strpos($this->key(), "default_") === 0);
    }
}

$list = new RemoveDefaultIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
var_dump(iterator_to_array($list));
```

They would all Output

```
array
  'default_E17' => string '0.009' (length=5)
  'default_H17' => string '0.0236' (length=6)
  'default_K17' => string '50' (length=2)
  'default_P17' => string '0.0118' (length=6)
  'default_E19' => string '0.03' (length=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd originally thought about this, but wondered if there was a more efficient way than looping through the entire array. It'd appear not!

Comment: Please see updated code with the use of `===` instead because `==` can return `0` when a `boolean` response is received

Comment: a speed test on each method could be helpful ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
 foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) { //iterate the array
  if( strpos($k, 'default_') !== FALSE  ) //search if the key contains 'default_' 
   $default_values[] = $v;   // if so, store the values for the 'default_' keys   
 }
```

Comment: Ran your code out of curiosity and it does not work see http://codepad.viper-7.com/9DjEKz . It returns `My App` which should not be in the list

Comment: Edited the conditional check.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over your array

```
Foreach( $inputArray AS $key=>$val ) {
  // check if key is the one we need
  if( ... ) {
     // it is - deal with it
  }
}
```

depending of the keys you use `if()` can be simple `substr()` or regexp matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FilterIterator for this.

Its essetially the same as looping over the whole array, because that's the only way really, but it strips you from doing this in your productive loop, thus generating less noise.

Here's how:

```
class Default_FilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
      if (strpos($this->key(), 'default') === 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
}


$yourArray = array('default_stuff' => 'foo', 'otherstuff' => 'bar');

$filterdArray = new Default_FilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($yourArray));

foreach ($filteredArray as $key => $value) {
  //deal only with default values here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
     // check if the $key starst with 'default_'
     if (substr($key, 0, 8) == "default_") {
      //do your thing...
      echo "<input type='text' value='" . $value . "'>";
     }
   }
```